# DynamicLanguageRuntime ERROR when I install IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ironpython

I need to use IronPython package in a .NET Framework project but when I am going to install the package an exception is thrown.

The following appears on the console:

```
Install-Package : No se puede resolver la dependencia 'DynamicLanguageRuntime'
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It *might* be complaining about [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicLanguageRuntime/).  Ask the package author about the version number you need.

Comment: @ECF could you please provide additional details (version of IronPython you are installing, .net version you are targeting, how nuget is invoked)?